# Installing Android SDK on Ubuntu (12.04 or above) 64 bit without ia32-libs

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, 64-bit, android

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

After following the [official steps](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk) to install Android SDK and ADT bundle on a Linux machine, I wasn't able to run the SDK as some of the binaries in it needed 32 bit libraries.

Almost all the highly voted answers to this quandary in this forum and elsewhere suggest the installation of `ia32-libs`.

For reasons, I simply could not install `ia32-libs`. I had this exact problem 6 months ago, at which I was able to follow the solution provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136394/cannot-install-ia32-libs) to install this package. But now even this doesn't work anymore and the error being `package not available`.

So instead of installing (or trying to install) `ia32-libs`, I would like to install the minimal set of 32 bit libraries that are needed by the Android SDK for my 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 OS. So what is this minimal set?

From my initial search the minimal set seems to be: `lib32z1`, `lib32ncurses5`, `lib32bz2-1.0`, `lib32stdc++6`. But I am not sure.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/423089/202806) would really help you.Let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The directory that you pointed to in that post is empty in my machine. So, I don't have a `multiarch` file or any other file there.

Answer (score 1):

From my initial search the minimal set seems to be:

`lib32z1`, `lib32ncurses5`, `lib32bz2-1.0`, `lib32stdc++6`.

After installing the above 4 packages, the Android SDK binaries were all happy on my machine.

I feel the exact answer could be a subset of the above 4.

All I can state is that `sudo apt-get install`-ing the above 4 has installed the required libraries for the 32-bit SDK binaries on my 64 bit machine without having to install the `ia32-libs` package.