# Remove .deb package from ubuntu

Tags: package-management, dpkg, software-installation

I installed a debian package  libncurses5-dev:i386.deb using "sudo dpkg -i libncurses5-dev:i386.deb".

However i realized that i needed another package libncurses5-dev_5.7+20100313-5_amd64.deb.

When i tried to install this one i got an error " libncurses5-dev: 5.7+20100313-5 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libncurses5-dev:i386 5.9-4 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
Errors were encountered while processing:".

I tried to remove libncurses5-dev:i386.deb. I went to /var/lib/dpkg/info and then sudo rm libncurses* to remove all the packages. I tried to install my amd64 package again but i get the same error message saying it cant install with libncurses5-dev:i386 5.9-4

Also when i do dpkg --list | grep -i libncur*, i dont see any results, so i am a bit confused
Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Version 12.04 LTS

Comment: 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Its 64 bit. x86_64

Comment: follow this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/423089/202806

Answer (score 2):

The command you should have used is

```
$ sudo dpkg -r libncurses5-dev
```

You should not have removed any files in `/var/lib/dpkg` by hand.

Comment: When i do dpkg --list | grep -i libncurses5, i get:              

ri  libncurses5                                5.9-4                               shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncurses5:i386                           5.9-4                               shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncurses5-dev:i386                       5.9-4                               developer's libraries for ncurses     

How to delete these from the system? sudo dpkg -r libncurses5-dev does not work.

Comment: @srai Deleting libncurses5 is probably not a great idea - many terminal programs depend on it, so you would end up deleting half of the system. libncurses5-dev, on the other hand, as it is only a development package, should be safe to remove. Given the status of the packages (ri for libncurses5 and ii for libncurses5-dev), maybe you could try `sudo echo "libncurses5 install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections` (taken from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166003/how-to-set-the-package-selection-status-to-the-current-status)) and then try the removal command again. Please post any error you get.