# dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

Tags: skype

I tried to install skype using this tutorial 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype
But I got troubles at the first step

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

When I wrote this, I got this message

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture
Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages
[*]; Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values; 
Type dpkg--force-help for a list of forcing options; 
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or`more' !
```

What should I do ? 
I will be very thankful if you will explain all this step by step, because I never had Ubuntu before.

Comment: What you are looking for is here : http://askubuntu.com/a/423089/339536

Answer (score 0):

According to your guide, that's just for MultiArch support, I think that's already enabled by default in current Ubuntu's so it shouldn't matter... but apparently Ubuntu 12.04 (if that's what you're using, not sure at this time) isn't "fully multiarch" so if you get the "unknown architecture" messages try these:

- Ensure the only file in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/` is `multiarch` then run `echo 'foreign-architecture i386' | sudo tee /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`
- `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
- `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"` (to make sure the partner section repository is enabled)
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype`

And if those give problems, `aptitude` is supposed to be more persistent, this might yield better results:

`sudo aptitude install skype`

Comment: Nothing happends when I write the 2nd line (Is it how it should work?)

Comment: After I write the 3rd line I am getting this message:                                                         Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: 2nd line says nothing when I am writing it (is it how it should work?

Comment: You've tried the 2 answers in the Q's comments already too? Which Ubuntu version are you using, anyway? 32/64bit? `lsb_release -a` should say. (2nd line adding parner probably worked, quiet is sometimes good)

Comment: 64bit, yes i tried one of them had the same problem

Comment: If all the linked Q's & suggestions have failed, then I don't know, could be some odd packages installed &/or held, maybe from unofficial ppa's or downloaded directly, or an old Ubuntu or something. I do know that on Ubuntu-based Mint 17 32-bit I just add all the "main restricted universe multiverse" repos, update then install skype, done. sorry I'm tapped out